# Parse a file without common delimiter in shell

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk

I would like to ask you for help with parsing a file in shell.

Here is my data:

```
ID:1 g-t="Demo one" rfid="af7e 25" t-link="http://demo.site.com/api2",User af73 25 http://example.com/useraf73
ID:2 g-t="Demo one" rfid="77 63" t-link="http://demo.site.com/api",User 77 http://example.com/user77
```

There is no common delimiter, basically I need these fields:

```
ID=1 | g-t="Demo one" | rfid="af7e 25" | t-link="http://demo.site.com/api2" | User af73 25 | http://example.com/useraf73
```

Here is where I am stuck:

```
awk '{match($0,"g-t=([^\" ]+)",a)}END{print a[1]}'
```

I am trying to match double quote with space but I have no idea why it is not printing the result. All the chars work fine except double quotes.
What I am doing wrong? Awk is not a must here, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: I would first specify the syntax of your lines precisely. For example, before 't-link', the field separator is a space, while the space after 'User' is not a field separator and the comma before it is one. If you can describe it with a regular expression, you can just loop through the file and apply the regexp to each line. Nearly any programming language would do...

Comment: IMO, using perl will be more handy for this task.

Comment: I followed your advice and defined my delimiters first with sed: sed 's/ /_/g' ; 's/^ *// s/ *$//'. After that it was easy...

Answer (score 1):

It has been quite a while since I regularly used awk but if I remember correctly match() takes only 2 args and END{} happens only once, not for every line like I think you want. Something like:

```
 awk '{match($0,/g-t="([^\"]+")/); print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' dataFile
```

may be closer to what you had in mind?

A brute force Perl one-liner could look something like this:

```
perl -lne 'if (m/ID:(\S+) g-t="([^"]+)" rfid="([^"]+)" t-link="([^"]+)",User (.*) (http:.*)/){print "$1|$2|$3|$4|$5|$6"}' dataFile
```

and demonstrates getting all of the fields data separated by OR bars. You can move the () groups around to get more or less of the text you want for each resultant $1, $2 etc... See **perldoc perl** for more information.